# concurrent ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, concurrency

I am trying to do concurrent ajax calls in jquery but I haven't found anything specific regarding it. When I make 2 ajax calls, another one is being started only after the first one is finished. I tried `$.ajaxSetUp{(async: true)}`, but it didn't work the way i wanted. Can anyone help me with this?

**[Edited]**
I have a form and on form submit I use the ajaxSubtmit of [form.js](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) as my form has `file input` as well.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $(this).ajaxSubmit();
  $.getScript("url");
  return false; // to stop the normal working of form submit and submit form by ajax
})
```

here the second ajax is called only after the first one is finished.

Comment: Post your javascript.  A call to `.ajax` won't clock like you are describing unless you've explicitly set `async: false`.

Comment: We need to see code - ajax calls do not block other ajax calls so something else is happening.

Comment: By the way... Your code doesn't actually send any ajax requests, it submits a hidden form to an iframe, and appends a script tag to the head. I'm not sure exactly what that means for your problem, but it definitely adds to the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that's what you said is called race condition.
To avoid it you have two options, either you create an array to store each request, or you create a local variable to store each request.
Here's a simple example that avoids the race condition:

```
function customCallBack()
  {//    Ajax Status finished       http status OK
    if( (this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200) )
     {
       alert(this.responseText);
     }
  }

function anotherCallBack()
  {//    Ajax Status finished       http status OK
    if( (this.readyState == 4) && (this.status == 200) )
      {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
  }


function asyncPost(url, postArray, functionCallBack)
  {
    var request, query; //request must be a local var to avoid race condition
    query = '';
    for (i in postArray)//format post params
      {
        query += i + '=' + postArray[i] + '&';
      }
    try
      {//for modern browsers
        request = new XMLHttpRequest;
      }
    catch (err)
      {// legacy IE
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
       // your custom call back function
    request.onreadystatechange = functionCallBack;
    //            type   url  true for async call, false for sync call
    request.open("POST", url, true);

    //Header sent to indicate a post form
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    //making a post call
    request.send(query);
  };

//calling

asyncPost('yourUrl', {'field1' : 'value1', 'field2': 10}, customCallBack);

var post = new Array();
post['field1'] = 'value1';
post['field2'] = 10
//calling againg
asyncPost('anotherUrl', post, anotherCallBack);


// In jquery is like above, because you need the ajax call in a custom function
// and create a local var to hold your call:
function jqAjax(url)
  {
    var mycall  = $.get(url);
  }
```

Comment: i did not understand what jqAjax function is for. It is not used anywhere. Can you please explain it a bit more!

Comment: Your solution works for the asynchronous calls. But they both stop at the same time. However, I would like to finish one ajax request while another one is running. Moreover, I would like the second ajax call to be periodic while the first one is running. Is there any way to do this? Moreover, my second ajax call is "GET" so will it be enough to change "POST" to "GET" only on `request.open`?

Answer (score 0):

Both Ajax calls are independent, if the first call delay to complete, then the second continues independently and you can make as many calls ajax you want: 10, 20, 30 ...

To change the method use the function below

```
function asyncCall(url, method, varArray, functionCallBack)
  {
    var request, query;
    query = '';
    for (i in postArray)//format params
      {
        query += i + '=' + postArray[i] + '&';
      }
    try
      {//for modern browsers
        request = new XMLHttpRequest;
      }
    catch (err)
      {// legacy IE
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    request.onreadystatechange = functionCallBack;
    if(method == 'GET')
      {
        request.open("GET", url + '?' + query, true);
        request.send();
      }
    else
      {
        request.open("POST", url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(query);
      }
  };
console.log('start 1');
asyncCall('url1', 'GET', {foo : 'bar'}, function(){console.log('Call 1');});
console.log('start 2');
asyncCall('url2', 'POST', {foo : 'bar'}, function(){console.log('Call 2');});
console.log('start 3');
asyncCall('url3', 'POST', {foo : 'bar'}, function(){console.log('Call 3');});
```

Comment: Errata if(method = 'GET') => if(method == 'GET')