# How to make concurrent and independent Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, xmlhttprequest

This is really really close to my problem: [concurrent ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963679/concurrent-ajax-calls)

When the user clicks a button, I want to make an request. The user can click the button multiple times, and each time a new XMLHttpRequest will be created. **Each request can start, process and finish independent of how many calls exists and in which state the others are**.

My problem is that the latest request only starts after the previous ended. I found several solutions using JQuery's deferred and promises, or using an array to store the calls, but either I didn't understand the answer or they don't solve my problem.

This is a simplified form of the function I use to create the request

```
library.flush = function (action, info, method) {
try {        
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        try {
            if (xhr.readyState == 3) {
                method.onProcess();
            }
            else if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                method.onReady();
            }
            else if (xhr.readyState == 1) {
                method.onStart();
            }
            else if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                method.onDone();
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("library.flush: xhr.onreadystatatechange error");
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    };
    method.onBeforeStart();
    xhr.open("POST", action, true);
    xhr.send(data);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log("library.flush: main error");
    console.log(e.message);
}
};
```

To be perfectly honest, I don't even know if what I'm trying to do is possible, but I guess it doesn't hurt to ask.

This is how I call library.flush

```
if (!Date.now) {
Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
}

$(".quickPost").keyup(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log("KeyUp fired");
    var data = {};
    data.URL = $('#quickDownload').val();
    data.type = $('#quickType').attr('value');
    if (!data.URL) {
        return;
    }
    this.blur();
    var events = {
        onBeforeStart: function () {
        },
        onStart: function () {
            console.log("Start " + Date.now());
        },
        onReady: function () {
            console.log("Ready " + Date.now());
        },
        onProcess: function (text) {
            console.log("Process");
        },
        onDone: function () {
            console.log("Done " + Date.now());
        }
    };
    library.flush('download', data, events);
}
});
```

This is how my Firebug console looks like

```
KeyUp fired //BEGIN REQUEST 1
Start 1425752652632 //REQUEST 1
POST {URL} //REQUEST 1
Ready 1425752655237 //REQUEST 1
6 Process //REQUEST 1
KeyUp fired //BEGIN REQUEST 2
Start 1425752655822 //REQUEST 2
POST {URL} //REQUEST 2
18 Process //REQUEST 1
KeyUp fired //BEGIN REQUEST 3
Start 1425752658950 //REQUEST 3
POST {URL} //REQUEST 3
7 Process //REQUEST 1
Done 1425752661221 //REQUEST 1
Ready 1425752666305 //REQUEST 2
35 Process //REQUEST 2
Done 1425752675168 //REQUEST 2
Ready 1425752677345 //REQUEST 3
28 Process //REQUEST 3
Done 1425752684975 //REQUEST 3
```

Comment: You can initiate as many concurrent requests as you want, but browser's have a maximum limit of concurrent request and will queue exceeding ones.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, but this happens even if I have only 2 requests. The second only starts after the first ends.

Comment: How are you calling `library.flush`? In a loop? You are correctly passing `true` for the `async` param of the `open` method, so I do not see what could be wrong. It's either you reached the maximum number of concurrent requests or that you aren't properly calling on the function.

Comment: No, I call it on a keyup event. I updated the question with details.

Comment: Well, how much time gets elapsed between these log entries? It could just be that the first request finishes before the next one changes state. What's happening when you have more than 2?

Comment: With 3 requests the log starts to get a bit messy. I tried to add a timestamp to see the difference, but it's pretty useless. The important thing is:  the "Ready" message shows up a few seconds *after* the "Done" message of the previous request, regardless of how soon I started the request. Notice that "KeyUp fired //BEGIN REQUEST 3"  happens even before "Done 1425752661221 //REQUEST 1", but the request only starts to be processed after "Done 1425752675168 //REQUEST 2"

Comment: Also: see how the "Process //REQUEST 1" logs are separated by other log messages? This tells me that the requests *are* happening async, but for some reason they aren't happening *concurrently*.